# Using stash:get_list as plugin parameter value

Tags: stash, parse-order, list

Can't seem to get this to work.
See comments: https://gist.github.com/timkelty/6996339

```
{exp:gwcode_categories
  group_id="2"
  style="linear"
  show_empty="no"
  parse="inward"
  entry_id='{exp:stash:get_list name="resource" backspace="1"}{entry_id}|{/exp:stash:get_list}'
}
  {stash:cat_name}{cat_name}{/stash:cat_name}
  {stash:cat_id}{cat_id}{/stash:cat_id}
{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is parse order. In your code {exp:stash:append_list name="resource"... Is three levels deep. Think layers of an onion. Whereas your {exp:gwcode_categories... is two levels deep but also requires the "resource" var which has not yet been parsed.